# iOS SDK: Conjoined Text Fields

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I don't know if I'm completely missing the boat here or what, but I can't figure out how to achieve conjoined email/password text fields like on the [flow login screen](http://pttrns.com/logins#/detail/197a554559f7cee9321e667ecc794719). Any help is appreciated!

FYI: I'm using XCode 3.2.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a custom table view cell with a label and a text field in a grouped table view probably with a single section and two rows one of which is for username and other for password. The logo could be the table view's header.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was hoping there was a different way to do this, but this will work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler solution that requires no code. 
If you have Photoshop, all you need to do is:

1. Make a new file (I recommend using the size of iPhone/iPad so you get the right size of the box you will make)
2. Use the Rounded Rectangle tool to make your box
3. Use the Line Tool to divide it up into the rows you want
4. Then just add it to your app as an image
5. Use text inputs with no borders, size them, and wa-la!

Super easy even for those not familiar with Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

Using XCode, Interface Builder, and Storyboards and Static Content.
UITableViews with static content are a new feature in Xcode 4.2 that allow tables to be designed WYSIWYG. Cells can be dragged into the table and customized by changing properties and adding controls. In previous versions of Xcode each cell would be a separate XIB file.